# Expandable search box placeholder does not work in internet explorer 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, placeholder

All browsers working fine with this script except IE. I am not using pure java or jquery. Using only css. I think that the problem is with transition, but i cant understand why. How can i solve this problem?

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dW92N/4/)

**HTML**

```
<form id="demo-2">
  <input type="search" onfocus="placeholder='some text'" onblur="placeholder=''" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input { outline: none; }

input[type=search] {
    font-family: inherit; 
    font-size: 100%; 
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}

input::-webkit-search-decoration, input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    display: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px; 
    border:none; 
    height:35px; 
    -moz-transition: all .5s; 
    transition: all .5s;
 }


 #demo-2 input[type=search] {
width: 100px;
padding-left: 10px;
color: transparent;
cursor: pointer;
 }

 #demo-2 input[type=search]:focus {
background:url(http://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
width: 626px;
padding-left: 32px;
color: #000;
background-color: #fff;
cursor: auto;
 }


 #demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
    color:red;
 }

 #demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color:red;
 }

 #demo-2 input::-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color:red;
 }
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for any answers!